# iPad and iTunes syncing

Tags: itunes, ipad, music, home-sharing

**When my wife travels to the south later this year, will she able to play her iTunes music on her iPad2 at her dad's home?** Will she simply need to log into his home network to do so?

Basically, we have the music which he doesn't, and we're trying to determine how to best share our music at his home. (Note: my wife's iPad is synced with our iMac, and the music is a combination of iTunes purchases and our own CDs that have been ripped to the iMac). Her dad will be in California next week; can he simply log into my network (iTunes account) and access my music? Or is the issue the fact that he and I have separate iTunes accounts?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Are you trying to *stream* music on your wife's iPad to their iTunes so you can play it from their speakers, or are you trying to *give* them (permanently) your music? I added the [tag:home-sharing] tag, but perhaps it should be [tag:transfer] tag or something? Would you be willing to clarify your question some? Perhaps it would be better if you removed the last two question as they seem a little confusing in light of the first ones

Comment: Thanks for the response. Let me clarify. My wife can stream the music on her iPad2 to our home theatre via Apple TV. We have one iTunes acct for our purchases, etc..When she goes to visit family in Ga. is there a way she can stream the same music via her dad's home theatre/Apple TV set up. I'm assuming there's an issue related to our iTunes acct vs her dad's iTunes acct.

Comment: I'll add this to the transfer tag as well